# How to access certain element of a static webpage(html not accesible) through javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, element, addeventlistener

Here i want to invoke a certain function on click the element of class "btn"...and by pressing the space(keycode = 32)...but its not working.....what i m doing wrong?
NOTE: i m unable to access the html code...trying to make it work just by USING SCRIPT

```
<body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="autocreate-submit">
              <div class="panel-body">
               <br/>
                <form id="command" role="form" style="display:inline;" class="form-inline" action="Nextpage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" tabindex="2" class="btn" value="Next" />                       
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    <script>
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
            alert("Mouse clicked")});
        document.addEventListener('keypress', function(x){
           if(x.keycode === 32){
           alert("Space pressed")};
        });
    })();
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Kindly cross-check if your script gets injected in a separate dom from that of html which you intended to, cases like using iframes can be an issue which you are facing.

Comment: Could you please help me on that...

Answer (score 0):

Dhaval, you can access certain element in a html document using its classname by using the code below for example.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0]
```